# I am unable to install app in shopify after selecting npm run dev

Tags: shopify

I run npm run dev and then following error came

[Error showing cloudflaire tunnel not working][1]

Then I tried to download ngrok and took the URL from there as follows

[Taking URL from ngrok][2]

And then when I run the command again I am getting following error

[Error][3]

I am unable to install the app. (I am following the tutorial https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/getting-started/build-qr-code-app?framework=remix)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMAVY.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKbnr.jpg
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gzOx.jpg

Comment: you can try this 

`npm run dev -- --reset --tunnel ngrok`

if does not work then try this

Install Ngrok from https://ngrok.com/download
Run ngrok http 3000` from the terminal and copy the generated URL for the next step
`npm run dev -- --tunnel-url https://example.ngrok.com:3000`

Answer (score 0):

First, check the internet connection.
if it is possible you can use yarn

To work on the following, please follow these steps:

1. `npm run shopify auth logout`
2. Install Ngrok from https://ngrok.com/download
3. Run `ngrok http 3000` from the terminal and copy the generated URL for the next step.
4. Run `npm run dev -- --tunnel-url https://example.ngrok.com:3000`.

Comment: Hi mate thanks but now I am getting new error

FetchError: request to https://partners.shopify.com/api/cli/graphql failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND partners.shopify.com

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue after changing the build in package.json to "build": "shopify app build" and then I ran npm run shopify app build and then I npm run shopify app dev and I am now succesfully connecting it.